# Property of limits of a power

Tags: real-analysis, limits

I would like to solve this exercise and I don't know how to start.

Given $a, b \in \mathbb{R}^+$ with $a = \lim_{n}{a_n}$ and $b = \lim_{n}{b_n}$, $a_n, b_n \in \mathbb{Q}^+$, if $a^b$ exits, then $a^b = \lim_{n}{a_{n}^{b_n}}$.

I know how to solve it with the exponential and logarithm functions, but I have to solve it with the $\epsilon$ definition of limit.

In other demonstrations, we've used the triangular inequality, so I've tried that:

$|a_{n}^{b_{n}} - a^b| = |a_{n}^{b_{n}} -a_{n}^b + a_{n}^b - a^b| \leq |a_{n}^{b_{n}} -a_{n}^b| + |a_{n}^b - a^b|.$

I don't know if in the second term I can use that $\lim_{n}{a_n^k} = a^k$, I think I can, but the first term is so confusing for me.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Haven't you made any effort yet?

Comment: I've edited the post.

Comment: Hint: given the continuity of $\exp$ (which has an epsilon-delta proof) you can reduce this to [a similar result concerning products](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Combination_Theorem_for_Sequences/Real/Product_Rule).

Comment: For the first term, you can use the mean value theorem and the fact that $(a_n)$ and $(b_n)$ are bounded.